# Trying to set X-Frame and CSP to display another websites login page but connection refused

Tags: x-frame-options, content-security-policy, referrer-policy, x-content-type-options

I am trying to get X-Frame and CSP to work but nothing I do seems to work and I get refused to connect. Even if I remove the header completely, it still gets blocked, I have tried adding Allow-From or AllowAll but nothing works. Same for CSP, it does not work, the frame is trying to load I think a javascript page.

How do I get this to work? I am using IIS and editing the web.config file

Comment: Are there default headers present for X-Frame-Options or CSP? X-Frame-Options and CSP frame-ancestors define who can frame your page, so if you want to frame another page you should look into CSP frame-src. What does the console error messages say?